# Node.js heap difference between v10 and v16

Tags: node.js

I have node.js v 10.24.0 on a ARMv7 2GB RAM machine. I also tried installing node.js v16 LTS on the same machine and when I check heap statistics using both the versions, I get different values. For example, `heap_size_limit` is  `775389960` in node `10.24.0` but `490471424` in node `16.17.1`.  I checked the release notes for every version after v10, but didn't find any concrete answers. So, why is the difference in the values?

Results using v10.24.0

```bash
$ /usr/bin/node -v
v10.24.0


$/usr/bin/node
>
> v8.getHeapStatistics()
{ total_heap_size: 9437184,
  total_heap_size_executable: 1572864,
  total_physical_size: 6356052,
  total_available_size: 766792248,
  used_heap_size: 5046920,
  heap_size_limit: 775389960,
  malloced_memory: 8192,
  peak_malloced_memory: 4391308,
  does_zap_garbage: 0 }
>
```

Results using v16

```bash
$/usr/local/bin/node -v
v16.17.1

$node
Welcome to Node.js v16.17.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
> v8.getHeapStatistics()
{
  total_heap_size: 3436544,
  total_heap_size_executable: 786432,
  total_physical_size: 2668968,
  total_available_size: 488251980,
  used_heap_size: 2551164,
  heap_size_limit: 490471424,
  malloced_memory: 73772,
  peak_malloced_memory: 419824,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 1,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0,
  total_global_handles_size: 4096,
  used_global_handles_size: 1968,
  external_memory: 2043833
}
>
```

Comment: What's your exact issue? That the objects have different keys? That the values are different?

Comment: Sorry I missed adding the actual question. I have updated the question now.